# Black Screen problem after setting ubuntu 12.4

Tags: 12.04

I having problem with ubuntu 12.4.I am using win 7, I set up it and after that I open my computer , it doesn't work , all is black screen and nothing else.
I put my Win 7 CD to set up again and I  have been waiting to see what's going on with my laptop? haven't any result.
Could you help me to solve this problem? I am really need to fix because I used my laptop for studying.

Comment: what have you set up? Did you installed ubuntu 12.04 or trying to test it via live mode? what happens when you boot with windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. what i did was right click and select change desktop background, 
all settings, additional drivers, update and restart.
at the log in, click the icon and select Ubuntu 2D, and log in.